# JMETER- Hide password value and a key value in User Defined Varialble

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMETER. I have the password and a key value set as the  User Defined Variable.

Question is how to hide it. Say if password is 123456  then replace it by ******

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is NO direct way to do it. You can raise an enhancement request!

If your sampler has the 'Username', 'Password' fields you can use Login Config Element (not 'uname' etc).

[image]

But - if you open the .jmx file in your Text Editor - You can see the Password you have set. Not good!!

[image]
**Approach 1:**

Pass the Password via command line like a property. Access it with __P()

**Approach 2:**

You can store the encrypted password - decrypt it with Beanshell preprocessor.

But - still - 'View Results Tree' might show the passwords if you access it.